# installing two version of a software

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I downloaded and installed a program  from **source**. Now I want to install a newer version, again from **source**. In both cases I have to add PATH to bashrc. I am a afraid from upcoming problems, because I think when I type NS (my program) in the terminal, Linux will not know which one to *expose*? Is it a correct *criteria*?

Comment: @AdityaPatil thanks, you mean when you type ns1 or ns2 in terminal it works? If yes rename in where I am sure not just folder. rename in where bashrc or where?

Comment: you can do it in bashrc. ns2 will point to the source compiled one and you would not require to make change for the one that is already present.I could try this when I get access to my computer.but I'm sure that this would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install two softwares having same name into two different directories, one in /usr directory is called.

If both are installed in places other than usr, the one which is located first is used(that's what I think)

In your case, you must change name of either package in bashrc, for ex change to NS2 which will point to one of the app you will compile.The other will be pointed by NS.This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you compile both versions in different directories then you can just use one or the other directory in your PATH variable.

Say you had a directory named NS-1.0.0 and the binary ended up under /bin in there:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/my-name/NS-1.0.0/bin
```

Now you compile version 1.3.7, so the binary ends up in a new directory and you can change your PATH to the following:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/my-name/NS-1.3.7/bin
```

If you installed the software under /usr/bin/... or /usr/local/bin/..., then installing the new version is likely to overwrite the old version. However, you have no guarantee that it will work properly in case some files from the old version need to be deleted.

If you kept everything local, then the change I shown should suffice.